# How to remove get_header From all single pages in wordpress with functions.php without plugin?

Tags: php, functions, filters, headers, wp-head

I want to remove get_header and get_footer conditionally and temporary from all single pages with functions.php

i tried this remove action with conditions code but not works..

```
remove_action('get_header', 'wpx_remove_header', 1)
```

please suggest me best way to do that..

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how your site is set up, but typically the get_header and get_footer is called in a template file. If you are using the typical template hierarchy, then your single pages are using single.php and both get_header and get_footer can simply just be removed from that php file.